# Fetching SVG from Flask

Tags: python, android, android-studio, flask, svg

I am creating an Android app in which an SVG image is fetched from a Flask server. This is the Kotlin-Jetpack Compose code:

```
@Composable
fun SvgUrlFetch() {

val imageUrl by remember { mutableStateOf("http://ip_direction/get_svg") }

Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    Image(
        rememberImagePainter(
            data = imageUrl,
            builder = {
                decoder(SvgDecoder(LocalContext.current))
            }
        ),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
}
```

And this is the Python-Flask one:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def generate_svg():

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [10, 15, 13, 18, 16]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)

svg_output = BytesIO()
plt.savefig(svg_output, format='svg')
plt.close()

svg_output.seek(0)

return svg_output

@app.route('/get_svg', methods=['GET'])
def get_svg(): 
svg_file = generate_svg()

return send_file(svg_file, mimetype='image/svg+xml')

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()`
```

When I access the URL direction of the Flask server, I see the image displayed successfully.
However, when I try to fetch the image from Android Studio using the SVG decoder (which has successfully accomplished the task of fetching SVG images from the Internet), I get a white screen and this error:

> E/studio.deploy: Exception
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
> at com.android.tools.deploy.instrument.ResourceOverlays.getPackageName(ResourceOverlays.java:94)
> at com.android.tools.deploy.instrument.ResourceOverlays.updateLoader(ResourceOverlays.java:65)
> at com.android.tools.deploy.instrument.ResourceOverlays.addResourceOverlays(ResourceOverlays.java:37)
> at com.android.tools.deploy.instrument.InstrumentationHooks.addResourceOverlays(InstrumentationHooks.java:110)
> at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1434)
> at android.app.ContextImpl.createSystemContext(ContextImpl.java:3365)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.getSystemContext(ActivityThread.java:3038)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7243)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2416)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:257)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:368)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8815)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:572)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)

I have been looking for articles, help or examples on the Internet for a while, but I have not found anything. I would be pleased if anyone could help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would appear that your error is coming from the IDE preview. I do not think that `LocalContext.current` works in previews. Are you sure that you need it? [The documentation](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/svgs/) shows `SvgDecoder.Factory()`.

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare, thank you so much for your answer. I do not think that is the problem. In the documentation Local Context is mentioned everywhere, and to me it has no sense, as using Local Context, I am able to fetch SVG images from the Internet. However, the particular SVG image from my LocalHost is apparently impossible to fetch.